# React conditional classnames using template strings and && operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class-attributes, template-strings

There have been many questions on StackOverflow relating to applying conditional classnames to React components; however, I have not seen a good answer for this particular situation:

I have a basic div that I want to conditionally apply the "is-required" class. Here is my approach:

```
<div className={`some-class ${isRequired && 'is-required'}`}>
```

The main issue here is that when isRequired is false, then my compiled HTML code ends up looking like this:

```
<div class='some-class false'>
```

Obviously, I could use a ternary operator like this so I can return an empty string instead:

```
<div className={`some-class ${isRequired ? 'is-required' : ''}`}>
```

But then in the compiled HTML code there is this extra random space included in the class, which won't cause any rendering issues, but I still don't like it:

```
<div class='some-class '>
```

Even still, I could remove the space after "someClass" and include it before "isRequired", but now it's harder to read and feels kind of clunky:

```
<div className={`some-class${isRequired ? ' is-required' : ''}`}>
```

I have heard of utilities such as classnames, but I am looking for a simple solution where I don't need any additional packages.

What is the recommended approach here?

Comment: Does `isRequired` is a boolean or a string?

Comment: isRequired is a boolean.

Comment: Voted to close as too opinion based. Personally I just use ternaries in template strings with a space between each expression rather than inside of them.

Comment: `[…].filter(Boolean).join(" ")` should be simple enough.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, there are many ways to do that, here's one of them.

```
<div className={isRequired ? 'some-class is-required': 'some-class'}>
```

or you can return `null`

```
<div className={isRequired ? 'is-required' : null}>
```

In order, if you have several classes.

```
<div className={isRequired ? 'some-class is-required': isDisabled ? 'some-disabled-class' : 'some-class'}>
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isRequired: false
    };
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <div className={this.state.isRequired ? 'is-required' : null}>Null</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't empty string be better than null? Not sure what null would produce.

Comment: It would produce nothing if I used an empty string it would produce a space.

Comment: Must be a React thing then because `new String(null)+""
` produces "null" for me so would be `<div class="some-classnull"` when isRequired is false(y)

Comment: What about a situation where I have several classes I want to conditionally apply? So kind of like this: `${isRequired && 'is-required'} ${isDisabled && 'is-disabled'}`.

Comment: @DrewJex assuming that isRequired and isDisabled is an empty string then do your some-class first and all optional classes with a leading space after that: ${isRequired && " is-required"}

Comment: @HMR yes you are right it's returning a null as well, I just fixed them

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you'll find this utility function helpful (it will be used as a tagged template):

```
const c = (strings = [], ...classes) => {
  let myClass = '';
  strings.forEach((s, i) => {
    myClass += s + (classes[i] || '');
  });

  return myClass.trim().replace('  ', ' ');
}
```

Now you can use it like this :

```
className={c`my-class ${this.props.done && 'done'} selected`}
```

or

```
className={c`some-class ${isRequired && 'is-required'} ${isDisabled && 'some-disabled-class'}`}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use it if you don't want false value.

```html
<div className={`some-class${isRequired && ' is-required' || ''}`}>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div className={isRequired && 'is-required'}>Required</div>
```

Using evaluation short circuiting (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using this package for joining class names if you are using an import/export system.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

Answer (score 0):

> className={`rounded-lg   ${isActive ? "bg-violet-600" :
> > "bg-slate-600"}`}>

There are three classes here:

1. rounded-lg
2. bg-violet-600
3. bg-slate-600

Note:

- I want to appy rounded-lg always
- And if isActive true, select bg-violet-600 otherwise bg-slate-600